# Multiply tuple pairs

Tags: python-3.x, string, integer, tuples, transform

I need to make a function to multiply two strings and give an integer list

I have to turn

```
L="1 3 5 7"
N="4 -1 2 0"
```

to

```
[4, -3, 10, 0]
```

So far I have this but I am not sure how to define the function

```
l=L.split()
n=N.split()
l1=map(int,l)
n1=map(int,n)
z=zip(n1,l1)
print(list(z))
def transform(x):
    for i in x:
        for j in x:
            yield i*j
print (list(transform(z)))
```

I would gladly appreciate any advice

Comment: So what's the meaning of "multiply" in this context?

Comment: BTW: `def func(L,N):` at the beginning, and `return` instead of `print` at the end.

Comment: they want me to multiply each string in L with their corresponding string in N

Comment: Your expected output implies that they want addition, not multiplication!

Comment: I am not what math are you studying but `1*4 != 5`

Comment: Sorry I made the list out of the top of my head because I didn't have the data here and mess it up. it is a multiplication. sorry I was thinking about something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to your expected output - it's a *sum* but not *multiplication*:

```
L="1 3 5 7"
N="4 -1 2 0"

def sum_str_items(s1, s2):
    return list(map(sum, zip(map(int, s1.split()), map(int, s2.split()))))

print(sum_str_items(L, N))
```

The output:

```
[5, 2, 7, 7]
```

---

A *"multiplication"* version could be implemented with [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap) function:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import mul

L = "1 3 5 7"
N = "4 -1 2 0"


def mul_str_items(s1, s2):
    return list(starmap(mul, zip(map(int, s1.split()), map(int, s2.split()))))

print(mul_str_items(L, N))
```

The output:

```
[4, -3, 10, 0]
```

Comment: Sorry it is a multiplication I just made a mistake sorry

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful